# What forms of ID do I need to fly domestically from Massachusetts after October, 2018?

Tags: usa, paperwork, domestic-travel, real-id

I am planning to fly to Texas in a few weeks, but I do not have a Real ID. I have a standard Massachusetts license and a passport, and the passport is going to expire within 6 months.

To fly domestically would I need to renew my passport (even though it is technically still valid)? Do I even need my passport at this time -- would my standard license still work?

Comment: You could fly to Canada with a passport expiring even next week, as long as you were planning to return home before the passport expired.  I don't see why you wouldn't be as well off flying domestically within the US.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to renew your passport; you can use it up until its expiration date.

You can also use your driver's license as long as your flight is before October 1, 2020.

Here's what the TSA [has to say about it](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification):

> Identification
>
> Adult passengers 18 and over must show valid identification at the airport checkpoint in order to travel.
>
> - Driver's licenses or other state photo identity cards issued by Department of Motor Vehicles (or equivalent)
> - U.S. passport
> - U.S. passport card
> - DHS trusted traveler cards (Global Entry, NEXUS, SENTRI, FAST)
> - U.S. Department of Defense ID, including IDs issued to dependents
> - Permanent resident card
> - Border crossing card
> - DHS-designated enhanced driver's license
> - Federally recognized, tribal-issued photo ID
> - HSPD-12 PIV card
> - Foreign government-issued passport
> - Canadian provincial driver's license or Indian and Northern Affairs Canada card
> - Transportation worker identification credential
> - U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services Employment Authorization Card (I-766)
> - U.S. Merchant Mariner Credential
>
> Beginning Oct. 1, 2020, if you plan to use your state-issued ID or license to fly within the U.S., make sure it is REAL ID compliant. If you are not sure if your ID complies with REAL ID, check with your state department of motor vehicles.
>
> For information on REAL ID, please visit DHS frequently asked questions.